# How can I directly link to my SO account?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, hyperlinks

I want to add a link to my Stack Overflow account on LinkedIn. How can I get this direct link? I checked my profile, but there is nothing like a link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1577396/venkateshwar

Comment: shoooooooooooooooot first step is wrong. :) thanks btw

Comment: I realised this after posting here. From next time I will think thrice before posting.

Comment: @venkateshwar Don't tell them you made this post ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your account. At the bottom you will see all your Accounts. Just copy the link of the desired account.

[image]

Or visit your Stackoverflow account and copy the URL from your browser.

Comment: You can also just copy the link from the address bar when you're viewing your profile on whatever site you want to link to.

Answer (score 6):

Access your profile in the site you want to link to, then copy the current URL.

In case you want more than just a link, create a cool banner by going to `.../<yourProfile>/flair`:
[image]

And it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It's very useful for me. But unfortunately I cant even upvote it :) may be later.

Comment: upvoted...... :)