# Is it correct to crop images to remove unnecessary background?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, images

Not everybody takes the time to correctly crop images, sometimes I see posts that contain images that show too much background (more than necessary).

While *some* background in general is useful, much of it [can cause](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147879/179635) the following inconveniences:

- It make us spend more time than necessary
- They take more time load
- Not saving resources

Is it correct to crop images and re-upload them?

<sub>**Related:** [Resizing an image in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post) this is to make the image dimensions smaller, not to *crop* parts of the image, if we make an image that shows too much background smaller, the only thing we will achieve is to make it hard to read (just like this text)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this would be a problem at all.  The revision history will still have the link to the old image, so if for whatever reason there is something important you cropped out without realizing it you can always do a rollback.

Another option to consider (although I wouldn't say you *have* to do this), if the image is displayed as an image rather than a link, would be to do your cropping, show the cropped image in the post, and then include a link to the full sized image underneath it.  This will help reduce clutter in the post without taking away information that might potentially be valuable.